# Type inference when using complex "isEmpty" check

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I have the following function which works like [ramdas isEmpty](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/master/source/isEmpty.js), but tailored to my own needs:

```
/**
 * Checks if a value is empty.
 * It will return true for the following cases:
 * null, undefined, empty string, empty Set, empty Map, an object without properties.
 * @param input Can be any value.
 * @example
 *
 *     isEmpty([1, 2, 3]); //=> false
 *     isEmpty([]); //=> true
 *
 *     isEmpty(''); //=> true
 *
 *     isEmpty(null); //=> true
 *     isEmpty(undefined); //=> true
 *
 *     isEmpty({}); //=> true
 *
 *     isEmpty(new Set([1, 2, 3])); //=> false
 *     isEmpty(new Set()); //=> true
 *
 *     isEmpty(0); //=> false
 *
 *     isEmpty(new Date()); //=> true
 *     isEmpty(Date.now()); //=> false
 */
export const isEmpty = (input: any): boolean => {
  const isMapOrSet = input instanceof Map || input instanceof Set;
  return input === null
    || input === undefined
    || (input instanceof String ? input.length > 0 : false)
    || (isMapOrSet ? input.size === 0 : false)
    || (!isMapOrSet && input instanceof Object ? Object.keys(input).length === 0 : false);
};
```

Using this function is pretty straightforward, but I'm unhappy with the `boolean` return type because TypeScript cannot infer the null checks that this function provides.

For example, the following code is perfectly fine, but TypeScript will complain about a possible null at the `someResult[0]` call.

```
const someResult: [] | null = getStuffFromAPI();
const x = isEmpty(someResult)
? {}
: someResult[0]; // TypeScript will complain about a possible _null_ here.
```

So the question is:
**How can I improve the function's signature, so that TypeScript can properly infer the return type?**

I tried to model a custom return type by utilizing [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html), but I couldn't figure out how to it correctly.

To make it a 100% clear what I'm searching for, here's some *pseudo code* (please note that `HasNoElements` and `IsEmpty` do not exist in TS):

```
type IsEmpty<T> =
  T extends null | undefined ? true :
  T extends Map & HasNoElements ? true :
  T extends Set & HasNoElements ? true :
  T extends String & IsEmpty ? true :
  T extends Object & IsEmpty ? true :
  false;
```

Maybe I'm overthinking this, but I'd like to broaden my horizon a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been solved by improved type inference for generics in [TypeScript 3.4](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-4/). So in my example above I basically get all the correct type signatures I wanted for "free".